Is a sequence number as a key ID always problematic (replay attack)?
I would like to know whether a sequence number as a key ID is always problematic with regard to replay attacks. I am aware that there are several interesting aspects (predictability, overflows, collision risk, ...). But first, consider the following case:
Peer A wants to join a secure group communication. The security association (SA) for this (key, key ID, algorithms, etc.) is obtained by a peer via an encrypted and secure channel from a key server, as long as it is authenticated and authorised. All peers in a group receive identical SAs (same symmetric key and same key ID) from the key server. Therefore we speak about a shared group SA. However, SAs expire after a specified period of time, so peers periodically obtain a new SA (with a fresh key and new Key ID) from the key server. A peer always keeps the 'current SA' and the 'next SA' in its memory, so that in the event of a periodic SA rotation in the group, all peers can continue to communicate seamlessly ('next SA' becomes 'current SA'). It is a bit more complex in detail, but should suffice here.
When the key server generates a new group SA, the key ID (which is initialized with 0) is incremented by one. The key, on the other hand, is renewed with a cryptographically secure random number generator.
The reason for using an increment instead of RAND() or H(Key) is the early detection of outdated SAs at the peers in the event of a replay attack. If a peer receives a secured message with the key ID 123, it can be discarded directly if the peer has a KeyID of 140 in the current SA. This means that packets can be discarded without having to calculate and compare the checksum first.
Assuming that the key server reboots (key ID is reset to 0) or the key ID overflows and an attacker sends a packet to the peer with a matching key ID, this would not be a problem either. The key behind the key ID would be different (because the key is a random value) and this would be detected when checking the checksum.
Now for my questions:
Is the predictability of the key ID in this case a security risk? Is there a particular attack vector that I may not be aware of?
Thank you.

"All peers in a group receive identical SAs from the key server." I presume you mean functionally equivalent SAs if they contain the key ID right? And "The key behind the key ID would be different (because it is a random number)..." probably means "The key behind the key ID would be different (because the key is a random value)...". If so please [edit] the question. On a side note, things like "I have been struggling with a question for a while now and hope that one or two of you can help me or give me some tips." and "Kind regards, SBond" are only distracting, please leave them out.

Thank you! I hope I'm not bothering you too much. As I saw, descriptions were missing in the text, which I had probably somehow deleted. I hope the description is now clearer.
